# js_on_event on Div widget in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

Is it possible to use `js_on_event` for `Div` widgets? I would ultimately like to trigger a callback in python whenever an event is triggered on a `Div` widget (tap, press, mouse enter, mouse leave, etc), and I suppose going through `js_on_event` is the way to do that(?). Anyways, I have tried the following:

```
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Div

from lib.bokeh.util.bokeh_util import display

div = Div(style={'background': 'gray', 'min-width': '500px', 'min-height': '500px'})

div.js_on_event(events.Tap, CustomJS(code="""
    console.log("Does this work?")
    """))

display(layout(div, sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
```

But this does not seem to have any effect.

`display` is a convenience function that fires up a bokeh `Server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger Python callbacks, you'd need `on_event`. `js_on_event` is for triggering JS code in browser, without any communication with the server.

But either way, the `Tap` event works only on instances of `Plot` - it doesn't work on any other model, even if it has a visual representation.

There are two ways to solve your problem. If you just need something simple like the `Tap` event, you can (and probably should) use the regular `Button`. But if you need something more complicated, you can create a custom Bokeh model that would process any JS events, convert them to Bokeh events, and send them to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know of any examples that is related to this and could be a good starting point for me? Do I just have to extend the Model class and add appropriate code? I could perhaps look at the source code for the Button widget for instance? I have tried reading the bokeh source code before though, and it can be rather challenging, so that would be a last resort.

Comment: @MartinRindarøy Sure, there's a generic example here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch :)